# starting activity from a list

Tags: android, list, android-activity

I'm trying to start a different activity everytime an item is clicked on a ListView but I only succeded to start a single new activity using intent but if I want to pass an activity from an array of activities I get stuck here's my code maybe someone get the same problem

```
public class ListViewExample extends ListActivity{   String[] presidents = {
    "Dwight D. Eisenhower",
    "John F. Kennedy",
    "Lyndon B. Johnson",
    "Richard Nixon",
    "Gerald Ford",
    "Jimmy Carter",
    "Ronald Reagan",
    "George H. W. Bush",
    "Bill Clinton",
    "George W. Bush",
    "Barack Obama"
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, presidents));
}
public void onListItemClick (
    ListView parent, View v,
    int position, long id) 
    {   


     String[] desires = {

             "AutoCompleteExample",
             "BasicViewsExample",
             "DateTimePickerExample",
             "ListViewExample",
             "ViewsActivity",
             "AutoCompleteExample",
             "BasicViewsExample",
             "DateTimePickerExample",
             "ListViewExample",
             "ViewsActivity",
             "AutoCompleteExample",
     };


    Intent i = new Intent(desires[position]);
    startActivity(i);


}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a String array use a class array

```
Class<?>[] desires = {AutoCompleteExample.class,
                      BasicViewsExample.class,
                       //etc
                      ViewsActivity.class};
  Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, desires[position]);
  startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  indeed. I'm new to developing app so I didn't know many basic things...have an happy time.